# How to get all file information by path?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function that returns all information about the file using the path as parameter? I need a information just like $_FILES array has: name,type,tmp_name(i already have this),error and size.

For example:

```
$file = get_file('path/to/file');
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes; take a look at `finfo_file` function.

According to the official documentation found @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

> **finfo_file** -- finfo::file — Return information about a file

Procedural approach:

```
string finfo_file ( resource $finfo , string $file_name = NULL [, int $options = FILEINFO_NONE [, resource $context = NULL ]] )
```

Object Oriented approach:

```
public string finfo::file ( string $file_name = NULL [, int $options = FILEINFO_NONE [, resource $context = NULL ]] )
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

That should work.

Comment: you are sure, this is what he asked for?